# How to define array of objects in Sequelize.js in NestJS for Postgres?

Tags: nestjs

How can I define an array of objects field in Sequelize.js model in NestJS for Postgres?
I need something like this

```
{
    userId: { type: String, required: true},
    products: [
        {
            productId: {
                type: String
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to translate the above code to NestJS using Sequelize.js, but using Postman I sent post requests and got an untyped object in the products array. And I don't understand how to solve this problem.

```
import {Column, DataType, Model, Table} from "sequelize-typescript";

export interface IProductItem {
    productId: string
    quantity: number
}

interface ICartsCreationAttrs {
    userId: number
    products: Array<IProductItem>
}

@Table({tableName: 'carts'})
export class CartsModel extends Model<CartsModel, ICartsCreationAttrs> {

    @Column({type: DataType.INTEGER, unique: true, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true})
    id: number

    @Column({type: DataType.INTEGER, unique: true, allowNull: false})
    userId: number

    @Column({type: DataType.ARRAY(DataType.JSON), allowNull: false})
    products: Array<IProductItem>

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For sequelize doesn't needs a type definition in an array or JSON object. You can define only column types.

(JSONB allows only for Postgress)

```
 products: { type: JSONB, required: true}
```